# How much energy (in electronvolts) is released when each flavor of quark decays?

Tags: particle-physics, quarks

I am creating a game about particle physics. I would like to know how much energy, in electronvolts, is released when a quark decays into something else. I've seen the decay process and the times required for decay, but I don't know exactly how much energy is released when a quark decays into another flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I first mentioned in a comment, the canonical source for all your particle data quandaries is the [PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/).
For example, if you are interested in the decays of the top quark, you can go to the [top quark page](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/listings/rpp2020-list-t-quark.pdf). There on the first page, you will see the best combined measurement of the top quark mass (172.76±0.30 GeV), along with a list of references to experimental data used to derive this figure. Then you can scroll down to page 11 (in the 2020 edition) and find a list of the decay modes, along with their relative probabilities. Depending on how detailed you want to be, you could make your game respect these probabilities.

Having selected a decay mode that you are interested in, the amount of kinetic energy released in the decay would be the difference between mass of the top quark (or whatever you start with) and the sum of the masses of the things produced in the decay. You can find those masses on the corresponding pages of the PDG. Those particles in turn may also be unstable, and you will find their decay modes on their pages as well. You can then build up a whole cascade of decays until in the end you have only stable particles remaining.

However, there is one complication to this simple picture that you may want to consider. All of the quarks *except* the top quark [hadronize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadronization) before they decay. Likewise quarks that may be produced in the decay hadronize again before they decay further, or before they are detected if they are long-lived. That means they get packaged up with other quarks and gluons into composite particles called hadrons. These hadrons can have masses much higher than the masses of the individual quarks. In this case, it is the masses of the hadrons that are important for computing the amount of kinetic energy that is released. So except for the top quark, you would need to first decide which hadron you want your quark to be living in, then look up that hadron's page in the PDG and use that mass and the masses of its decay products.

You specifically ask about quarks, but you probably also have leptons in your game. Leptons are fortunately much simpler. They don't hadronize, so the mass given directly in the PDG is the mass you can use. (But heavy leptons can decay *into* quarks, in which case again you'll have to look for the appropriate hadrons for those quarks.)

Answer (score 0):

In special relativity, which holds in the particle frame, [the difference in masses](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/quark.html) in electron volts between the higher mass quark and the lower mass quark is available for masses and kinetic energy for the [decay products.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qrkdec.html) .